# Feign - URL encode path params

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-feign, feign

This is my contract,

```
@RequestLine("GET /products/{id}")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
ApiResponse getProduct(@Param("id") String productId) throws Exception;
```

I want to fetch the product with id = "a/b",

If I send this as a param to `getProduct("a/b")`

then the URL that is formed is `http://api/products/a/b` and I am getting a 404 instead the url should be `http://api/products/a%2Fb`

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I am using <dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
   <artifactId>feign-core</artifactId>
   <version>9.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple config did it,

```
@RequestLine(value = "GET /products/{id}", decodeSlash = false)
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
ApiResponse getProduct(@Param("id") String productId) throws Exception;
```

The path param was correctly getting encoded but the RequestTemplate was decoding the URL again (decodeSlash=true by default) before sending out the request which was causing the issue.

Comment: I found the same problem. IMHO it should be a default behaviour :/ If I am passing a path argument, it should be from now on simply encoded till the end... :/ Thanks anyway for showing the solution

Comment: Thanks, this lead me in the right direction. In my case the FeignClient was generated by the openapi-generator so I couldn't change it straight away but I had to adapt the templates. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58712381/1326662

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when code looks like this:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/document/{documentId}/files/{fileId}")
  ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDocument(@PathVariable("documentId") String documentId, @PathVariable(value = "fileId") String fileId);
```

Also problem was that @PathVariable `fileId` could be `123/SGINED`.

Setting application.property `feign.client.decodeSlash=false` helped.