# Adding decodeSlash using Feign @RequestLine

Tags: java, yaml, okhttp, rest-client, feign

I am currently using a YAML file to generate the models and the API clients using the swagger plugin and I am using Feign OkHttpClient to make requests to the API, the problem here is the client encodes the URL but ignores the Slash(es) with this the API call fails. Is there a way to add `decodeSlash` parameter in the client? Or can this be achieved using an interceptor?

Here is the sample path param where I am running into this issue. `QgKuK2DU/0%3D` where as it should be `QgKuK2DU%2F0%3D`

Answer (score 0):

`decodeSlash` can only be set via the `@RequestLine` annotation.  If you do not have access to the annotation you will need to replace the `uri` using a `RequestInterceptor`.

Comment: Where does the @RequestLine need to be added exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [openapi-generator](https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator) you can [modify the templates](https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/wiki/FAQ#i-want-to-use-customized-templates-for-java-feign-client-how-can-i-do-that) (also described [here](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating)) yourself to add the `decodeSlash` Parameter:

```
git clone https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator
cd openapi-generator
git checkout v4.2.0 # The Version Tag you are actually using
cd modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/feign/
cp api.mustache <your_local_project>/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/feign
```

In `api.mustache` change the 2 appearances of `@RequestLine`:

```
- @RequestLine("{{httpMethod}} {{{path}}}{{#hasQueryParams}}?{{/hasQueryParams}}{{#queryParams}}{{baseName}}={{=<% %>=}}{<%paramName%>}<%={{ }}=%>{{#hasMore}}&{{/hasMore}}{{/queryParams}}")
+ @RequestLine(value="{{httpMethod}} {{{path}}}{{#hasQueryParams}}?{{/hasQueryParams}}{{#queryParams}}{{baseName}}={{=<% %>=}}{<%paramName%>}<%={{ }}=%>{{#hasMore}}&{{/hasMore}}{{/queryParams}}", decodeSlash = false)

- @RequestLine("{{httpMethod}} {{{path}}}?{{#queryParams}}{{baseName}}={{=<% %>=}}{<%paramName%>}<%={{ }}=%>{{#hasMore}}&{{/hasMore}}{{/queryParams}}")
+ @RequestLine(value="{{httpMethod}} {{{path}}}?{{#queryParams}}{{baseName}}={{=<% %>=}}{<%paramName%>}<%={{ }}=%>{{#hasMore}}&{{/hasMore}}{{/queryParams}}", decodeSlash = false)
```

Using the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` add the `templateDirectory` to the `<configuration>` block:

```
<templateDirectory>src/main/resources/Java/libraries/feign</templateDirectory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a contract in the Feign client interface and turn of the decode slash:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "yourClient", url= "xxxx", configuration = YourClient.ClientConf.class)
public interface YourClient {
  class ClientConf{
     @Bean
     Contract contract(@Autowired(required = false) List<AnnotatedParameterProcessor> parameterProcessors, ConversionService feignConversionService) {
         if (parameterProcessors == null) {
             parameterProcessors = new ArrayList<>();
         }
         return new SpringMvcContract(parameterProcessors, feignConversionService, false);
     }
  }
}
```